# Same string, but var_dump shows weird data

Tags: php, string, comparison, var-dump

I have a variable `$username` that I substring from a url string, which I get from a file.

This is the output of `var_dump($username)`:

```
"tring(18) "honorablevacuum87
```

if I set `$username = "honorablevacuum87"` and I var_dump it, I get:

```
string(17) "honorablevacuum87"
```

What is the problem. I am getting insane over this.

Comment: After Edit: those are different because the first one got a type (a blank space maybe) at the end of the string, used $myString = trim($myString); ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have opened the file in binary mode instead of text mode, which means that no end-of-line translation is happening.

```
$fp = fopen('foo.txt', 'rt');
```